# Clear a TBitmap before changing it in Delphi (VCL/Windows)

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-2007, tbitmap

This is about Delphi, 32 bits and Windows/VCL:

For a procedure that takes an input bitmap and writes to an output bitmap with a given format (PixelFormat: pf8Bit with a gray scale palette) I use the following code:

```
procedure ConvertBitmap(_inBmp: TBitmap; _outBmp: TBitmap);
begin
  _outBmp.PixelFormat := pf8Bit;
  _outBmp.Palette := MakeGrayPalette();
  _outBmp.SetSize(_inBmp.Width, _inBmp.Height);
  // code that works on ScanLines goes here
end;
```

The Output bitmap might not be empty when it is being passed to this procedure, but might contain anything in any format. It will be completely overwritten in the procedure.

I wonder whether simply changing its PixelFormat might create some overhead (e.g. convert the old content to the new pixel format), so should I somehow clear it first, e.g. by calling _outBmp.SetSize(0, 0) or any other means? If yes, what would be the most efficient way?

EDIT:

I just did some timing with this code:

```
procedure TimingTest;
var
  Stopwatch1: TStopwatch;
  Stopwatch2: TStopwatch;
  bmp: TBitmap;
  i: Integer;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Stopwatch1 := TStopwatch.Create;
    Stopwatch2 := TStopwatch.Create;
    for i := 0 to 10 - 1 do begin
      bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
      bmp.SetSize(16 * 1024, 8 * 1024);
      Stopwatch1.Start;
      bmp.PixelFormat := pf8bit;
      bmp.Palette := MakeGrayPalette();
      Stopwatch1.Stop;
    end;
    for i := 0 to 10 - 1 do begin
      bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
      bmp.SetSize(16 * 1024, 8 * 1024);
      Stopwatch2.Start;
      bmp.SetSize(0, 0);
      bmp.PixelFormat := pf8bit;
      bmp.Palette := MakeGrayPalette();
      Stopwatch2.Stop;
    end;
    l_Timing.Caption := Format('%.3f [s] vs %.3f [s]', [
    Stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000, Stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000]);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(bmp);
  end;
end;
```

The result on my computer (which is not slow):
5.331 [s] vs. 0.322 [s]

Unless I made an implementation error, this is quite significant. This is admittedly with a rather large bitmap though, but even with a more resonable size of 4096x4096 I get 0.693 vs. 0.040 which is still significant if this operation is executed many times (which it will be: several million times in fact).

This answers the question of whether there is a performance impact with a clear yes.

The remaining question is: Is SetSize(0,0) the most efficient way to clear a bitmap or is there a better way?

EDIT2:

TBitmap.Assign(nil) is another way to clear the bitmap:

```
    for i := 0 to 10 - 1 do begin
      bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
      bmp.SetSize(16 * 1024, 8 * 1024);
      Stopwatch3.Start;
      bmp.Assign(nil);
      bmp.PixelFormat := pf8bit;
      bmp.Palette := MakeGrayPalette();
      Stopwatch3.Stop;
    end;
```

The timing is similar to .SetSize(0, 0).

Comment: Do you have an actual problem with the code as it stands?

Comment: Not a problem as such, but the code in total (including the one hiding behind // code that works on ScanLines) could need some performance improvement. I have so far reduced the number of calls to TBitmap.ScanLine[], which helped a lot, and reduced the PixelFormat from pf24Bit to pf8Bit, which also got some microseconds. Now I'm looking into other areas and this just struck me as a possible performance improvement. (Before you ask: No, I haven't done any timing yet, but I am in the process of doing that.)

Comment: It's pointless asking how to clear a bitmap (whatever that even means) when you don't know whether that has any benefit. You should be trying to optimise your code based on measurable data.

Comment: It's not pointless to ask if I want to know how to do it. It might not significantly improve the performance of this code but I still want to know.

Comment: OK, here is the timing: without SetSize(0,0) it takes 5 seconds, with it takes only 0.3 seconds for changing the PixelFormat of a 16*1024 by 8*1024 bitmap.

Comment: It's pointless to ask without measurable data. Having done the measurement you are now in a position to ask.

Comment: I still don't understand your objective (nor your measurements). specially when you state: `"It will be completely overwritten in the procedure"`.  suppose the answer is "yes". Don't you still need to set your out bitmap to the desired size? i.e. `bmp.SetSize(0, 0);`... etc ... `bmp.SetSize(16 * 1024, 8 * 1024, 16 * 1024, 8 * 1024)`? what does the measurements tell you after you set it to the desired size?

Comment: The desired size depends on the input bitmap of the procedure. I need to force the output bitmap to PixelFormat = pf8bit. The original content of the bitmap might be anything from an empty bitmap to a very large one with PixelFormat = pf32bit. As my timing test shows it takes some significant time to change a large bitmap from PixelFormat = pf24bit to PixelFormat = pf8bit, so it is worthwhile to clear it first before changing the PixelFormat. I also did some timing with smaller bitmaps (640x480) and setting it to 0x0 first still saved a significant amount fo time.

Comment: I mean what happens to timing when you "clear" the bitmap + set it to the new size? also, in compare to simply creating a new 8 bit bitmap from scratch.

Comment: Even setting the bitmap back to the original size after changing the PixelFormat doesn't change timing much: 5,343 vs. 0.674 vs. 0.656 (with the large bitmap of the timing code above). It's a factor of 10 instead of 20. If I set it so a lower size (640x480) the timing is back to the original values.

Comment: 0.324s is the same as 0.322s, that's well within the bounds of variability. I would regard `Assign(nil)` as the canonical way to clear the instance. However, I would probably choose to create a new bitmap instance. And if you care about performance, then you might well look to a library like graphics32.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Can graphics32 manipulate 8 bit bitmaps?

Comment: @kobik Don't know, very possibly not

Comment: Creating a new bitmap instance is very costly. (Yes, I did timing on that, but not just now.) Graphics32 only handles 32 bit bitmaps which is not what I need. But yes, I might eventually switch to not using TBitmap at all but instead just manipulate an array of bytes.

Comment: 0.324 is of the same magnitude as 0.322, yes, but Assign(nil) is still consistently slower than .SetSize(0,0). As I plan to use this kind of procedure to process a few million images at a time, that might still make a difference. (1000000*0.0002 seconds is still 200 seconds which is 3 minutes). This optimizaton comes for free after all.

Comment: I have to correct this: Some more timing runs did not confirm that SetSize(0,0) is faster than Assign(nil). It's pretty much random.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said!

Comment: I guess you are wrong with the cost for TBitmap.Create. I need to increase the loop to 100 before seeing a timing in the milliseconds range. Even a Free/Create is about as fast as setting the size to 0.

Comment: @UweRaabe that's odd. I am sure my timings back then did show a significant difference between creating a new TBitmap and reusing an existing one.

Comment: Hm, but you timed it against callng bmp.Assign(nil), I timed something different back then. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: Create is really low cost. Free needs almost the same time as Assign(nil) or SetSize(0, 0).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but the test is flawed. The first set ends with a pf8bit correctly sized bitmap, the second is pf8bit 0x0. This is not the same. Somehow you don't allocate 10 times 16*1024 x 8 *1024 = 128MB bitmaps there.

The easiest option is of course to never change bittiness on existing bitmaps, but simply create a new one. With such large bitmaps, resizing and changing pixel type should be avoided at all costs if you care about performance.